# Modifying Grunt in Sails.js - task directory not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Trying to work with sails.js and like it so far. What am i doing wrong by running grunt by itself? if i do i get:

```
Tasks directory "node_modules/sails/node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin/tasks" not found.
```

This can be reproduced as follows:

```
sails new testProject
cd test*
grunt
```

The reason i am doing this this is to add an additional grunt task to watch for sass. Perhaps i do not need to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Without having the full `Gruntfile.js` or `package.json` I'm going to make assumptions.

### You don't have cssmin installed, and defined in your `Gruntfile.

This assumes you ran `npm install grunt-contrib-cssmin --save` and it installed it to `node_modules`

define the task in your Gruntfile..

```
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
```

Execute the appropriate tasks in the gruntfile.

### You have a syntax error somewhere

Post up your full gruntfile so we can adequately triage your problem and help you. Comment on my answer once you do so and i'll update my answer.

Comment: You're obviously missing a file or config step somewhere. I cant troubleshoot it further without seeing the gruntfile.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify further above.. Forget the other noise the question is really..